# Stop other audio when a new audio is Playing in flutter using audioplayers.dart package

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, flutter-dependencies, flutter-audioplayers

Code isn't working, the `audioplayer()` does not stop even after playing other sound and it keeps playing multiple sound simultaneously. I want to play one audio at a time and other audio to be paused instead of playing simultaneously.

There are several `TextButton` each assigned with different sound, but if I press three buttons one by one then each of the audio plays simultaneously on top of each other rather than stopping the previous one and only playing the latest button pressed even after using `player.stop()`.

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  void playSound(int soundNumber) {
    final player = AudioPlayer();
    player.stop();
    player.play(AssetSource('note$soundNumber.wav'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                child: Text("")
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  playSound(1);
                },
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                child: Text("")
              ),
              ...
            ])
        )
      )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In here you should define
`final player = AudioPlayer();` globally outside the function then use it

```
final player=AudioPlayer();
void playSound(int soundNumber){
player.stop();
player.play(soundExample);
}
```

Comment: thusithda Deepal thanks brother!!! For replying me instantaneously !!! Thanks a lot!!!! Will you explain thw working behind it? i am new to flutter and my first stackoverflow question i am glad you helped me out!

Comment: @adnanshaikh What your code currently does is that every time you click a new button, it creates a new `AudioPlayer()` and plays the sound. Since it's a new `AudioPlayer()`, there's nothing to stop, which is why you heard the overlapping sounds. With Thusitha's method, you only create one single `AudioPlayer` once, and when you call `player.stop()` and `player.play(soundExample)`, it's the same `AudioPlayer` that is doing the work.

Comment: @adnanshaikh  above comment explains the code,
you should use only one instance, so it is use in everywhere, in your code it creates new instance every time, that's why you listen multiple sounds at the same time.

Comment: @raw-chicken thusitha I perfectly understood my mistake. Once again I am very thankful too you both for helping me out!